# pandas reindex fill in missing dates

Tags: pandas, reindex

I have a dataframe with an index of dates. Each data is the first of the month. I want to fill in all missing dates in the index at a daily level.

I thought this should work:

```
daily=pd.date_range('2016-01-01', '2018-01-01', freq='D')
df=df.reindex(daily)
```

But it's returning `NA` in rows that should have data in (1st of the month dates) Can anyone see the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with parameter `method='ffill'` or [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with `ffill` for more general solution, because is not necessary create new index by `date_range`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(13)},
                   index=pd.date_range('2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', freq='MS'))

print (df)
             a
2016-01-01   0
2016-02-01   1
2016-03-01   2
2016-04-01   3
2016-05-01   4
2016-06-01   5
2016-07-01   6
2016-08-01   7
2016-09-01   8
2016-10-01   9
2016-11-01  10
2016-12-01  11
2017-01-01  12

daily=pd.date_range('2016-01-01', '2018-01-01', freq='D')
df1 = df.reindex(daily, method='ffill')
```

Another solution:

```
df1 = df.resample('D').ffill()
```

---

```
print (df1.head())
            a
2016-01-01  0
2016-01-02  0
2016-01-03  0
2016-01-04  0
2016-01-05  0
```